# Adding another check to Laravel's login auth

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, addition

I've used this command to create the auth for login, register and so on:

```
php artisan make:auth
```

I've changed the schema of my users table to have a field to determine whether the user can actually login.

I do not want all users to be able to login because some users are created to be related to another table and not to actually use the dashboard. I want to prevent unauthorised users losing in if they try to.

When the user logs in I want to run a check of this field to get the value and then perform an action based on that value.

I'm not sure on the best way to do this when using Laravel's auth.

Comment: It must be in authcontroller, the name of the method must be *postLogin()*

Answer (score 1):

Laravel auth provides a set of events and one is `Illuminate\Auth\Events\Authenticated` which triggers when the user authenticates.

You may add a listener to this and do your logic based on that.

Please refer:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/authentication#events

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/events#registering-events-and-listeners

Answer (score 0):

the previous answer by PSJ will defentley help you, another way to protect your dashbord, would be to assign roles to the users as a examle take a look at entrust or laratrust so you can check permissions for each view seperatly and for each Controller using Middelware. Works out off the box with laravel -auth.